# Orderer connection refused Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: yaml, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am trying to run the fabric-sample with tls settings removed.

The networks and all containers are running good without any errors but when I , try to run the channel creation command from cli, it is unable to connect to orderer container.

CLI Definition:-

```
version: '2'

services:
    cli:
        container_name: cli
        image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        environment:
            - GOPATH=/opt/gotpath
            - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
            - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
            - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
            - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
            - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
            - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
        working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
        command: /bin/bash
        volumes:
            - /var/run/:/host/var/run
            - ../../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode/
            - ../../chaincode-advanced/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/chaincode-advanced/
            - ../crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
            - ../scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
            - ../channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
```

Orderer Definition:-

```
version: '2'

services:
    orderer-base:
        image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
        environment:
            - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
            - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS:0.0.0.0
            - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
            - ORDERE_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
            - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
            - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
            - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=false
        working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
        command: orderer
```

Command failing to execute-

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c byfn-fabric-channel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx
```

Error:-

```
root@b7a8ed102a7b:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c byfn-fabric-channel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx
Error: failed to create deliver client: orderer client failed to connect to orderer.example.com:7050: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 172.21.0.2:7050: connect: connection refused"
```

Since TLS if off, certificates configuration should not be problem.Although cli container is able to ping orderer container.
But orderer on port 7050 is refusing connection, eventhough services on that port is running inside orderer.

Orderer Logs:-

```
2020-02-14 00:10:28.164 UTC [localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 001 Kafka.Version unset, setting to 0.10.2.0
2020-02-14 00:10:28.175 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 002 Orderer config values:
    General.LedgerType = "file"
    General.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1"
    General.ListenPort = 7050
    General.TLS.Enabled = false
    General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key"
    General.TLS.Certificate = "/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt"
    General.TLS.RootCAs = [/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt]
    General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
    General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
    General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.RootCAs = []
    General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
    General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
    General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
    General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
    General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
    General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
    General.GenesisMethod = "file"
    General.GenesisProfile = "SampleInsecureSolo"
    General.SystemChannel = "test-system-channel-name"
    General.GenesisFile = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block"
    General.Profile.Enabled = false
    General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
    General.LocalMSPDir = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp"
    General.LocalMSPID = "OrdererMSP"
    General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.Ephemeral = false
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = "/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp/keystore"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.InmemKeystore =
    General.BCCSP.PluginOpts =
    General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
    General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = false
    FileLedger.Location = "/var/hyperledger/production/orderer"
    FileLedger.Prefix = "hyperledger-fabric-ordererledger"
    RAMLedger.HistorySize = 1000
    Kafka.Retry.ShortInterval = 5s
    Kafka.Retry.ShortTotal = 10m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongInterval = 5m0s
    Kafka.Retry.LongTotal = 12h0m0s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.DialTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.ReadTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.NetworkTimeouts.WriteTimeout = 10s
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Metadata.RetryBackoff = 250ms
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryMax = 3
    Kafka.Retry.Producer.RetryBackoff = 100ms
    Kafka.Retry.Consumer.RetryBackoff = 2s
    Kafka.Verbose = false
    Kafka.Version = 0.10.2.0
    Kafka.TLS.Enabled = false
    Kafka.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Kafka.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Kafka.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Kafka.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Kafka.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Enabled = false
    Kafka.SASLPlain.User = ""
    Kafka.SASLPlain.Password = ""
    Kafka.Topic.ReplicationFactor = 3
    Debug.BroadcastTraceDir = ""
    Debug.DeliverTraceDir = ""
    Consensus = map[SnapDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/snapshot WALDir:/var/hyperledger/production/orderer/etcdraft/wal]
    Operations.ListenAddress = "127.0.0.1:8443"
    Operations.TLS.Enabled = false
    Operations.TLS.PrivateKey = ""
    Operations.TLS.Certificate = ""
    Operations.TLS.RootCAs = []
    Operations.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    Operations.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    Metrics.Provider = "disabled"
    Metrics.Statsd.Network = "udp"
    Metrics.Statsd.Address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
    Metrics.Statsd.WriteInterval = 30s
    Metrics.Statsd.Prefix = ""
2020-02-14 00:10:28.392 UTC [orderer.common.server] extractSysChanLastConfig -> INFO 003 Bootstrapping because no existing channels
2020-02-14 00:10:28.402 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 004 Getting block information from block storage
2020-02-14 00:10:28.598 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] Initialize -> INFO 005 Starting system channel 'byfn-sys-channel' with genesis block hash 46b45898fb2fadca600c5b423af9806a284c0d3c253917eca860c35b55935428 and orderer type solo
2020-02-14 00:10:28.598 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO 006 Starting orderer:
 Version: 1.4.4
 Commit SHA: 7917a40
 Go version: go1.12.12
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
2020-02-14 00:10:28.599 UTC [orderer.common.server] Start -> INFO 007 Beginning to serve requests
```

Comment: Can you share the orderer logs?

Comment: added orderer logs

Comment: @blazehub did you solved the problem?

Comment: its still not working without tls...with tls it seems to be working